# Linux "top" command - want to aggregate resource usage to the process group or user name, especially for postgres

Tags: linux, postgresql, process, aggregate, metrics

An important topic in software deveopment / programming is to assess the size of the product, and to **match the application footprint to the system** where it is running.  One may need to optimize the product, and/or one may need to add more memory, use a faster processor, etc.  In the case of virtual machines, it is important to make sure the application will work effectively by perhaps making the VM memory size larger, or allow a product to get more resources from the hypervisor when needed and available.

The **linux top(1) command** is great, with its ability to sort by different fields, add optional fields, highlight sort criteria on-screen, and switch sort field with < and >. On most systems though, there are very many processes running, making "at-a-glance" examination a little difficult.  Consider:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+   PPID SWAP nFLT COMMAND                                                                                                                                                        
 2181 root      20   0 7565m 3.2g 7028 S  2.7 58.3  86:41.17     1 317m  10k java                                                                                                                                                           
 1751 root      20   0  137m 2492 1056 S  0.0  0.0   0:02.57     1 5104   76 munin-node                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
11598 postgres  20   0  146m  23m  11m S  0.0  0.4   7:51.63  2143 3600   28 postmaster                                                                                                                                                     
 1470 root      20   0  243m 1792  820 S  0.0  0.0   0:01.89     1 2396   23 rsyslogd                                                                                                                                                       
 3107 postgres  20   0  146m  26m  11m S  0.0  0.5   7:40.61  2143  936   58 postmaster                                                                                                                                                     
 3168 postgres  20   0  132m  14m  11m S  0.0  0.2   8:27.27  2143  904   53 postmaster                                                                                                                                                     
 3057 postgres  20   0  138m  19m  11m S  0.0  0.3   6:55.63  2143  856   36 postmaster                                                                                                                                                     
 3128 root      20   0 85376  900  896 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.11  1636  852    2 sshd                                                                                                                                                           
 1728 root      20   0 80860 1080  952 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.61     1  776    0 master                                                                                                                                                         
 3130 manager   20   0 85532  844  672 S  0.0  0.0   0:01.03  3128  712   36 sshd                                                                                                                                                           
  436 root      16  -4 11052  264  260 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01     1  688    0 udevd                                                                                                                                                          
 2211 root      18  -2 11048  220  216 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00   436  684    0 udevd                                                                                                                                                          
 2212 root      18  -2 11048  220  216 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00   436  684    0 udevd                                                                                                                                                          
 1636 root      20   0 66176  524  436 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.12     1  620   25 sshd                                                                                                                                                           
 1486 root      20   0  229m 2000 1648 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.79  1485  596  116 sssd_be                                                                                                                                                        
 2306 postgres  20   0  131m  11m   9m S  0.0  0.2   0:01.21  2143  572   64 postmaster                                                                                                                                                     
 3055 postgres  20   0  135m  16m  11m S  0.0  0.3  10:18.88  2143  560   36 postmaster
```

...etc... This is for about 20 processes, but there are well over 100 processes.

In this example I was sorting by SWAP field.

I would like to be able to aggregate related processes based on the "process group" of which they are a part, or based on the USER running the process, or based on the COMMAND being run. Essentially I want to:

- **Aggregate by PPID**, or
- **Aggregate by USER**, or
- **Aggregate by COMMAND**, or
- **Turn off aggregation**

This would allow me to see more quickly what is going on.  The expectation is that all the postgres processes would show up together, as a single line, with process group leader (2143, not captured in the snippet) displaying aggegated metrics.  Generally the aggregation would be a sum (VIRT, RES, SHR, %CPU, %MEM, TIME+, SWAP, nFLT), but sometimes not (as for PR and NI, which might be shown as just --).

For processes whose PPID is 1, it would be nice to have an option of toggling between aggregating them all together, or of leaving them listed individually.

Aggegation by the name of the process (java vs. munin-node, vs. postmaster, vs. chrome) would also be a nice option.  The COMMAND arguments would not be used when aggregating by command name.

This would be very valuable when tuning an application. **How can I do this, aggregating top data for at-a-glance viewing in larger scale systems?**  Has anyone written an app, perhaps that uses top in batch mode, to create a summary view like I'm discussing?

FYI, I'm specifically interest in something for CentOS, but this would be helpful on any OS variant.

Thanks!
...Alan

Comment: [ps command](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_ps.htm)?

Comment: I usually sort on RES/RSS (or VIRT)